# delete operator with size on MSVC?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I would like to understand why does this code here works only on MSVC from what I have tested so far?

```
int main() 
{
    int* ptr = new int[14];
    delete[47.55F] ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried looking for the operators overloads of the delete operator but I couldn't find anything

Comment: Interesting. Here is a link: [https://godbolt.org/z/M9796cf7v](https://godbolt.org/z/M9796cf7v)

Comment: Yeah that's the weird thing...

Comment: *I would like to understand why does this code here works only on MSVC* -- Open a ticket with the Visual C++ engineering team and show them the issue.

Comment: Once upon a time, a `ptr = new int[14]` had to be matched with a `delete[14] ptr`. This requirement was removed over 40 years ago. Apparently there are remnants of this still present.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by passing parameters to `delete[]`?

Comment: @BoP yeah this makes sense i guess because I thought that an array size should always be an integer but I just tested and you can allocate an array in the heap that has a size in float so yeah, totally make sense. Thanks Microsoft!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was just curious because I came across this code today

Comment: So I just tested and when you put the size of the array in float number, MSVC will just cast it to an int. so I think perhaps MSVC will just ignore the argument and treat it as a normal delete operator

Comment: Looks like it just evaluates the argument whatever its type: https://godbolt.org/z/cW5axe3YK (So `delete [expr1] expr2` is converted to `(expr1, delete[] expr2)`). I wouldn't be surprised if this is just an edge case no one has ever used before and msvc just reused the "parse possibly-empty array bounds" code without forcing it to be empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete[47.55F]` is not valid syntax according to the ISO C++ standard in any edition. `delete[` can only be followed immediately by the token `]` or by the non-empty capture list of a lambda that is part of the operand of the `delete` (not `delete[]`) expression.

However, it seems that MSVC supports the syntax `delete[E] X` where `E` is any expression and effectively rewrites it to something like `((void)E, delete[] X)`, meaning that `E` is evaluated but its result discarded, while the actual `delete[]` expression is evaluated as if the non-standard expression `E` wasn't present. However, I couldn't find any documentation stating whether `E` is guaranteed to be sequenced before `delete[] X`.

This is a non-standard language extension that, as @BoP notes in a comment under the question, might be connected to a pre-standard syntax for delete expressions.

MSVC emits a warning for this at warning level 4 as noted by @JanSchultke in the comments under this answer.

MSVC also accepts the non-standard syntax with `/permissive-`, i.e. in standards conformance mode.

The documentation explains that this extension is activated with `/Ze` and can be deactivated with `/Za`, which seems to not be included in `/permissive-`. When using the flag `/Ze` MSVC also warns that the flag/extension is deprecated and will be removed in a later version.

Comment: I think @BoP comment is likely to be what's happening maybe

Comment: MSVC issues a `warning C4208: nonstandard extension used: delete [exp] - exp evaluated but ignored`. Use `/W4` to enable it. It's not a parser bug.

Comment: it still compiles after adding `/permissive-`